# jPlayer not looping properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I'm trying to create an audio playlist with jPlayer that will preload the next song in the list for seamless transitions, but I'm having some trouble with the looping feature.

I've got my code set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mz74e/

It uses 2 different players in order to preload the clips. The graphic UI is just shown for debugging, since I don't plan on using it in my final setup.

The current setup seems to loop properly in Firefox 12 and the flash player, but doesn't in Google Chrome 18 (It just goes to the beginning of the clip and sits there)

If anyone can look at how I'm using it and either figure out a workaround of a better implementation, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was not where I originally though it was.

This exact same code works fine if the audio file is statically served by the web server.

I found this code here for the rangeDownload function:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices

Using this, the files are distributed properly to be played by html5.